# Window wobbling in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-11

I simply want an app that could make the app window "wobble". This is what I mean by that:[image]. I'm using Windows 11. I do not want the app to be very heavy. Should be lightweight.

Comment: It might help with the answer if you tell us why you would like this.

Comment: I don't understand. :)

Comment: Sometimes if you explain why you want to do something, someone could suggest a different way to achieve it.

Comment: Oh i simply want the window to have a special effect.